# Emploi courant de la locution "Bouc émissaire"

Tags: locutions

La locution "bouc émissaire" est-elle répandue de nos jours ? Peut-on l'utiliser couramment pour parler d'une personne ou d'un groupe minoritaire auquel un groupe ou un peuple attribue injustement tous les malheurs, toutes les fautes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tant que locuteur natif du français vivant en France, ma réponse instinctive est **oui** (je serais intéressé par le point de vue d'un Québecois par exemple). Pour moi, cette expression peut être employée sans aucun problème et elle sera normalement comprise par l'interlocuteur.

[Une recherche sur Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bouc%20%C3%A9missaire&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbouc%20%C3%A9missaire%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbouc%20%C3%A9missaire%3B%2Cc0) semble corroborer mon point de vue, car elle montre que cette expression est de plus en plus employée (*au moins jusqu'à 2008, la limite du corpus de Google*).

[image: ngram bouc émissaire]

Answer (score 3):

Pour donner un point de vue du Québec, oui cette expression est très commune.

Je n'ai pas trouvé de graphique comme illustré dans la réponse de Reyedy, mais par contre j'ai fait une simple recherche d'actualités qui sort des résultats proches de moi et on voit facilement que l'expression est beaucoup utilisée dans les journaux;

[image]